# SplitView in iPad -- Maintain two views without popover

Tags: iphone, ipad

In a switch view mode in iPad, is it possible to maintain the two views in landscape mode and also in portrait mode without having to use the popover?(Maybe just adjust the width of each views in portrait, instead of the popover) How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in a number of ways.

For example have a view controller, with two additional view properties.  Add these as subviews to the view controller's view.

When the view controller appears and every time the view controller rotates, check the orientation and adjust the widths and positions of the views.  You many want to animate the properties to make it look nice.

Try to use the autoresizing properties of the views as this will make your live easier.

Let me know if you want example code.

Comment: Robert, I would be most grateful for some Sample code... David